# How to make sure my behavior is triggered before AJAX?

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have a form elements that looks like this:

```
  $form['properties'][$property->idProperty] = array(
    '#title' => $property->Label,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_filter_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'mymodule-filter-result',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'autocomplete' => 'off',
      'class' => array('exclusive'),
      'exclusivity_group' => array ( $property->ExclusivityGroup )
    ),
  );
```

The point of it is to have only one element from each group used at a time. To enforce that exclusivity, I created behavior like this:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.behavior_name = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('select.exclusive', context).on('change', function(){
        // Make all not selected
        $("[exclusivity_group='"+$(this).attr('exclusivity_group')+"']").not(this).find("option").attr('selected', false);
        // select "all"
        $("[exclusivity_group='"+$(this).attr('exclusivity_group')+"']").not(this).find("option[value='all']").attr('selected', true);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

*Note that both code blocks above are simplified, please don't criticize it too much as this is not actual code I'm using posted verbatim.*

How can I make sure my behavior acts before AJAX? If it happens to act after AJAX, I may end up with two fields set to something other than *'all'*, and that's specifically what I wanted to avoid. I may use `$triggering_element` to detect if it was one of "exclusive" fields, and I probably will, even if only as a secondary precaution, but I would strongly prefer to have things happening right in the JavaScript part.

---

I tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689787/2389310), but I don't think I understand how it works. I tried:

```
  $('select.exclusive', context).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    Drupal.ajax[$(this).attr('id')].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
      console.log(element.html());
    };
  });
```

First `console.log` returns IDs as expected. And it works, `beforeSend` is, indeed, changed as it should, it's function gets executed when needed. Sadly `console.log(element.html());` returns content of a whole form, not the triggering element of AJAX, so I'm not able to safely enforce exclusiveness - I don't know which element was changed last, so no way to select *other* elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now. The way to do it was:

- Get all elements that are in "exclusive" groups using classes, `.each` over them
- For each element, change `beforeSubmit` using `$(this).attr('id')` as index for `ajax` table
- Because I was not able to get `element` to point to a specific element (it always pointed to entire form), I used helper variable at the beginning of `.each` loop.

Resulting code is like this:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.behavior_name = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('select.exclusive', context).each(function(){
        var triggering_element = $(this);
        Drupal.ajax[$(this).attr('id')].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
          // Make all not selected
          $("[exclusivity_group='"+triggering_element.attr('exclusivity_group')+"']").not(triggering_element).find("option").attr('selected', false);
          // select "all"
          $("[exclusivity_group='"+triggering_element.attr('exclusivity_group')+"']").not(triggering_element).find("option[value='all']").attr('selected', true);

        };
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```